# In general which laser would cut clear glass more easily, a visible spectrum laser or an infrared laser?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, laser, infrared-radiation, glass

Assuming the two lasers have identical characteristics and power output except their wavelength, which one would be more successful and easy in cutting clear glass?

In case there is doubt that you can even cut clear glass with a laser, see here these two video demonstrations:

[Visible spectrum blue laser cutting glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3laSYjA2H3Y)

[Infrared laser cutting glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvjmHN1YAE0)

Secondly, what is the refractive index of glass at infrared wavelengths (~1.52 at visible white light)?

Comment: Refractive index database: https://refractiveindex.info/

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: The title of the 2nd video says it's cutting sapphire, not glass.  But the same (probable) 1064nm laser will be transmitted quite well through both

Comment: As for the 1st video, it looks like it wasn't even focussed, and it barely scored the glass rather than cutting it (that could even have been heating from the charring substrate rather than direct absorption)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont define what it means to cut easier, but I will address how you select wavelength to cut faster and how you can select wavelength to be more precise in your cuts (although this precision likely does not matter for the vast majority of laser cutting applications)

For lasers that differ only in wavelength, you would typically want to select the wavelength with the highest absorption in the material you want to cut, if everything else was equal. Photons that are reflected or transmitted through the material won't transfer their energy to the matetial you are cutting and therefore wont contribute to the cut. This way you maximize cutting speed. Obviously other considerations come into play with practical lasers, with laser power being a big one.

If you want to do extremely high precision cutting (micro/nanoscale), you will tend to want a shorter wavelength. Lasers with a shorter wavelength can be focused to a smaller spot size, increasing precision. This is only important at micro or nanoscale cutting.

There are other ways a laser can cut a material than by direct absorption in the material to cut, but I will ignore those for this answer since you have control of the laser wavelength.

Comment: "Photons that are reflected or transmitted through the material won't transfer their energy to the matetial you are cutting and therefore wont contribute to the cut."  This is wrong for high peak power lasers.  I've seen one of the most experienced laser engineers accidentally cut through a Bragg mirror (>99.99% reflectivity) using a pulsed laser.

Comment: "This way you maximize cutting speed."  In laser cutter I have used, the cutting speed is not limited by the laser.  It is limited by the thermal conductivity of the object you are cutting (they catch fire if you go too fast!) or by the stepper motors.

Comment: I think laser cutter resolution is also usually limited by the motors for cheaper cutters.

Comment: @Anonymous None of that is relevant to the question. It was purely about the laser aspects. If cutting at nanoscale precision we arent talking "cheap cutters".

Comment: @Anonymous I cannot believe you are claiming photons that are reflected or transmitted through a medium nevertheless transfer their energy to the medium. That just isnt true. Of course you can cut a Bragg reflector with 99.99% reflection. It is that 0.01% of absorbed photons who do the cutting. That is the entire point of my answer. All else being equal, a wavelength that is highly absorbed is more efficient. Or you are operating in one of the other laser cutting modes I said I wasnt going to address, such as ionizing the atmosphere.

Comment: I am claiming that photons that are reflected or transmitted in linear optics nevertheless transfer energy to the medium in nonlinear optics.  It's a widely reproduced experiment.  In the labs I've worked in, this was not negligible.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Yes I find this probable for reflected photons due to transfer of momentum but nevertheless the percentage effect would be small. Of course if the laser power is enormous even so the shock wave effect and pressure on the material would be in overall absolute values significant. In that case one could say that the lesar cuts the material due to radiation pressure! Good point.

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt. I've voted your answer as the best answer to the question as I find it to be the most relevant to what I'm actually asking and to the point. Sorry to see so far that the sum of votes in your answer is zero. I would like to both you and AnonymousPhysicist thank you for your precious expert insight you have shared and fruitful comments discussion.

Answer (score 4):

In industry, cutting lasers are not selected based on their wavelength.  They are selected based on their cost, which is closely related to energy efficiency.  Carbon dioxide lasers, which are infrared lasers, are used because they have the best energy efficiency.

"Clear" glass will absorb some portion of the infrared spectrum, as will any other solid. So some infrared radiation, depending on the wavelength, will cut the glass better than visible radiation, which is not absorbed.  The exact mechanism of cutting can vary.

It is also important to consider the geometry of the beam of radiation; owing to the diffraction limit, this is not independent of the wavelength.

Comment: "cutting lasers are not selected based on their wavelength" and "some infrared radiation, depending on the wavelength, will cut the glass better than visible radiation" seem to be in disagreement. Surely wavelength is important enough to be one of the factors in the decision.

Comment: @Matt No, cost is enormously more important than effectiveness.  I'm speaking from experience of having destroyed quite a few objects with lasers.  The most "effective" lasers are far more powerful (1000X if you limit it to CW) than what you need to cut glass.  Usually you just want to etch the glass, not cut it all the way.

Comment: The question asks about cutting glass, not etching, and ineffective lasers are a waste of money at any cost. How can you possibly rank cost above ability to do the intended job?

Comment: @Matt  Your questions are not really relevant because in practice almost all commercial laser cutters are CO2 laser cutters.  Wavelength is just not a consideration in the industry.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist So apart of any economic reasons,  in general  when it comes about cutting things larger wavelength infrared is more capable in cutting than smaller wavelengths more energetic beams E=Nhf say a blue leaser? Right? This seems to me counter intuitive, for the same number of photons N delivered, the blue laser should deliver more power on the cutting edge of the material? However, if I understood it correctly absorption of the beam is here the most important factor therefore low frequencies infrared $CO_{2}$ lasers win over visible spectrum lasers? Right?

Comment: Is there a material that this general rule for cutting does not apply?

Comment: This answer does not answer the question that was asked. The question assumed two identical lasers that differ only in output wavelength. This answer ignores the hypothetical and just says CO2 is common and additionly ignores any wavelength dependence of absorption that would matter if you ignore economic considerations, as was asked.

Comment: [1064nm laser cutters also exist](https://fslaser.com/mc-series-flatbed-fiber/).  1064 (near IR) will be much less efficiently absorbed in normal glass than the 10.6µm from a CO2 laser.  This doesn't necessarily make the CO2 a better choice if it's absorbed in a thin layer on the incident face

Comment: @Markoul11 No, I'd say your explanation is an extreme oversimplification of the physics, and it is not completely understood.

Comment: @Matt As mentioned in the last paragraph, the scenario in the question is not physically correct because of diffraction.

Comment: @Matt So, what you are saying? That the ideal best, thus faster and sharp cutting laser must trade-off between absorption and diffraction (i.e. spread of beam inside the material) characteristics? Therefore, choose a wavelength which offers the largest absorption with the less diffraction for a specific material?

Comment: @Markoul11 Yes, if everything else is equal. Although you probably dont care about the wavelength dependence on diffraction for most laser cutting applications.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Hi Anonymous Physicist.  Although I've upvoted also your expert answer, I've voted Matt's answer as the best answer to the question as I find it to be the most relevant to what I'm actually asking and to the point.  I would like to both you and Matt thank you for your precious expert insight you have shared and fruitful comments discussion.